# "with", context manager, python: What's going on in simple terms?

Tags: python, with-statement

Novice Python coder here coming from a Java background. I'm still puzzled by this:

```
with open(...) as f:
    do_something(f)
```

even after Googling and reading some of the answers here (I just couldn't get my head around them).

My understanding is that there is this thing called a context manager that is some sort of wrapper that contains a reference to a file that is created. Regarding

```
as f:
```

the 'as' above is like the 'as' below

```
import numpy as np
```

It's just an alias. 'f' doesn't refer to a file, but to the context manager. The context manager, using the decorator pattern, implements all the methods the file that is opened does, so that I can treat it like a file object (and get at the file object by calling the appropriate methods, which will be called on the file inside the context manager). And, of course, the file is closed when the block completes (the whole point of this).

This begs the question: Does open() in general return a file (or a reference to a file), or a context manager? Does it return context managers in general, and that's what we've been using all the time without knowing it? Or does it return file types except in this special context when returns something different like a context manager.

Is this anywhere near right? Would anyone like to clarify?

Comment: Files *are* context managers.

Comment: `with` after open just closes the file safely after the writing.

Comment: Have you read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ ?

Comment: @WayneWerner I looked at it, but I'm too much of a novice to get it.

Comment: Sorrrryyy for such a noob question. I was assuming something that caused the confusion: I didn't know a File could be a ContextManager simply by implementing two methods, without inheriting from a super class or explicitly implementing an interface. Again, I'm new to this language.

Comment: @Detroitteatime: The core Python language doesn't have explicit interfaces like Java has. The closest that comes to mind is are [Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), and for many common 'protocols' in Python, there are indeed [ABCs defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc). There is not such an ABC for context managers. Most Python interface checks are done through duck typing; if the methods are there, it must be implementing that interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File objects *are themselves context managers*, in that they have [`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__enter__) and [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#contextmanager.__exit__) methods. `with` notifies the `file` object when the context is entered and exited (by calling `__enter__` and `__exit__`, respectively), and this is how a file object "knows" to close the file. There is no wrapper object involved here; file objects provide those two methods (in Java terms you could say that file objects implement the context manager interface).

Note that `as` is *not* an alias just like `import module as altname`; instead, the *return value* of `contextmanager.__enter__()` is assigned to the target. The `fileobject.__enter__()` method returns `self` (so the file object itself), to make it easier to use the syntax:

```
with open(...) as fileobj:
```

If `fileobject.__enter__()` did not do this but either returned `None` or another object, you couldn't inline the `open()` call; to keep a reference to the returned file object you'd have to assign the result of `open()` to a variable first before using it as a context manager:

```
fileobj = open(...)
with fileobj as something_enter_returned:
    fileobj.write()
```

or

```
fileobj = open(...)
with fileobj:  # no as, ignore whatever fileobj.__enter__() produced 
    fileobj.write()
```

Note that nothing stops you from using the latter pattern in your own code; you don't *have* to use an `as target` part here if you already have another reference to the file object, or simply don't need to even access the file object further.

However, other context managers could return something different. Some database connectors return a database cursor:

```
conn = database.connect(....)
with conn as cursor:
    cursor.execute(...)
```

and exiting the context causes the transaction to be committed or rolled back (depending on wether or not there was an exception).

Answer (score 5):

This is the most basic context manager you could create:

```
class UselessContextManager(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

with UselessContextManager() as nothing:
    print(nothing is None)
```

If you want to get a little feel for what the actually process flow looks like, try this one:

```
class PrintingContextManager(object):                                          
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                       
        print('Initializing with args: {} and kwargs: {}'.format(args, kwargs))

    def __enter__(self):                                                       
        print('I am entering the context')                                     
        print('I am returning 42')                                             
        return 42                                                              

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):                                
        print('And now I am exiting')                                          


print('Creating manager')                                                      
manager = PrintingContextManager()                                             
print('Entering with block')                                                   
with manager as fnord:                                                         
    print('Fnord is {}'.format(fnord))                                         
    print('End of context')                                                    
print('Out of context')
```

Output:

```
Creating manager
Initializing with args: () and kwargs: {}
Entering with block
I am entering the context
I am returning 42
Fnord is 42
End of context
And now I am exiting
Out of context
```

You should try modifying the code to print out `type, value, traceback` and then raise an exception inside the `with` block.

As you can see, the `with` syntax is *almost* just short for:

```
thing = ContextManager()
try:
    stuff = thing.__enter__()
except Exception as e:
    stuff.__exit__(type(e), e.args[0], e.__traceback__)
```

[Though truthfully it's a bit different](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

You can see that files are always context managers:

```
>>> f = open('/tmp/spanish_inquisition.txt', 'w')
>>> f.__enter__
<function TextIOWrapper.__enter__>
>>> f.__exit__
<function TextIOWrapper.__exit__>
```

> I didn't know a File could be a ContextManager simply by implementing two methods, without inheriting from a super class or explicitly implementing an interface. Again, I'm new to this language.

In Python that *is* explicitly implementing an interface. In Java, you have to specify what interface you want to adhere to. In Python, you just do it. Need a file-like object? Add a `.read()` method. Maybe `.seek()`, `.open()`, and `.close()` depending on what they expect. But in Python...

```
it = DecoyDuck()
if it.walks_like_a_duck() and it.talks_like_a_duck() and it.quacks_like_a_duck():
    print('It must be a duck')
```

Answer (score 0):

Context managers are fairly simple beasts ... They're simply classes that define [two separate methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) ([`__enter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) and [`__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)).  Whatever is returned from `__enter__` is bound in the `as x` clause of the `with` statement when the `with` statement is executed.

Here's a really stupid example:

```
>>> class CM(object):
...   def __enter__(self):
...     print('In __enter__')
...     return 'Hello world'
...   def __exit__(self, *args):
...     print('In __exit__')
... 
>>> with CM() as x:
...   print(x)
... 
In __enter__
Hello world
In __exit__
```

You'll frequently see context managers simply returning `self` from the `__enter__` method, but I wrote the example above to demonstrate that you don't *have* to.  Also note that you don't need to construct the context manager in the `with` statement, you can construct it ahead of time:

```
cm = CM()
with cm as x:
    ...
```

The reason for context managers is that when used in conjunction with the `with` statement, python guarantees that `__exit__` will be called (even if an exception happens inside the `with` suite)<sup>1</sup>.

`file` objects are implemented using the context manager API (they have well defined `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods) so `file` objects *are* context managers.  When used with a `with` statement, python guarantees that when the `with` suite is exited, the file will be closed.

<sup><sup>1</sup>barring catastrophic system failure -- e.g. if your computer blows up...</sup>

Comment: So any class that implements the __enter__ and __exit__ methods a context manager. I got confused because I'm thinking in terms of inheritance or implementing an interface, but I see none of this for File.

Comment: @Detroitteatime -- I'm not sure that I understand.  On python2.5 -> python2.7 if you type `help(file)`, you'll see `__enter__` and `__exit__` listed there.  Perhaps the confusion is that `open` is a factory method which returns a file object?

Comment: @Detroitteatime: you can think of context managers as an interface anyway; file objects implement that interface.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I got confused because I was expecting to see something like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html somewhere in the docs where File implements an interface called ContextManager or extends a class called ContextManager. Now I know that this is not required for Python's File and context managers, and that clarifies everything. Thanks, I feel I get it now.

Comment: @Detroitteatime I explain it at the end of my answer - but it's not required for *anything* in Python - just implementing the particular methods and attributes that something uses.