# how to save a video although i kill the process

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

i am doing infinite loop to save a video , when i kill the process the file of the video don't open , although the size of the video is very big and this tell me that he is saving the file , but for some reason he can't open it, the release is out of the loop . i would be happy to get solution to this problem thanks

```
    while True:
        frame, frame_id, time_video = next(self.distributor_frame)
        if frame is not None:
            self.out.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    self.out.release()
```

Comment: Check the dimension of the frame and the dimension you declared for the writer `out`, make sure they're the same.

Comment: i check the frame and the size is the same

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to be able to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> out of the program, you can catch Python's built-in `KeyboardInterrupt` exception and then continue to close the resource.

```
try:
    while True:
        frame, frame_id, time_video = next(self.distributor_frame)
        if frame is not None:
            self.out.write(frame)
        else:
            break
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Stopped by keyboard interrupt')
self.out.release()
```

Normally, if you just send a SIGINT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) to stop the script, it will raise an exception in Python, and this exception will cut the program. However, you can intercept this signal with `except KeyboardInterrupt` and just simply do nothing, i.e., `pass` or `print` some message (like I did) or whatever you like. But since we caught the exception and aren't raising it again, the program doesn't end from the interrupt while inside that block.

---

Alternatively, subclass (or create a class that includes) the `VideoWriter` and give it a context manager---then even if you get an exception, the resource will be closed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38959585/5087436) has some good discussion about how to create a context manager yourself.

Comment: i am using pycharm and he doesn't catch the KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: @JoshKatz can you be a little more explicit? How precisely in PyCharm are you stopping the script? What do you mean by it doesn't catch it---as in you don't see the message printed, or the video is still not opening? Feel free to edit your original post and add these extra details in.

Comment: the video is still not opening , and he also don't print  the ('Stopped by keyboard interrupt') , first i stop with the regular stop button , now i am trying to do ctrl + c from the console but this way is not a good solution to my problem . thanks

Comment: @JoshKatz and how are you running your code? PyCharm does have multiple ways of running code, but I believe the standard way (through run) will catch the interrupt---I just tried it myself. However, I will note that this is a different question from what your OP stated, as this is a PyCharm specific question and there *are* questions on how to catch PyCharm's "Stop process" button in Python. The short of it is usually, you can catch it with a keyboard interrupt.

Comment: @JoshKatz to put it bluntly, using the stop button in PyCharm is *not* how you should control your Python application. It's there so you can *kill* your script if it's misbehaving, it's not there to provide controls for IO operations. Either way, see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13316) on JetBrain's tracker for more specific problems with catching the STOP PROCESS button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with classes, make sure you implement the `__del__` method to properly release the video when the garbage collector deletes your object.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, save_output_at:str, window_size_hw:tuple[int, int], save_output_fps:int):
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename=save_output_at,
                                            fourcc=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
                                            frameSize=window_size_hw[::-1],
                                            fps=save_output_fps)
    # [Your write bucles...]

    def close(self):
        """
        Release the video_writer.
        """
        if self.out.isOpened():
            self.out.release()
  
    def __del__(self):
        """
        Destructor.
        """
        self.close()
```